# Disable checkbox checked no listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Adicionei em meu `ListView` o `checkbox` padrão dele "ListView Checkboxes", quando ele estiver `checked` preciso desabilitar o mesmo para que não possa mais ser "check", tentei fazer com que o `checkbox` ficasse como `Enable false`, mas não consegui acessar ele, está tentando acessar pela propriedade `ItemChecked`.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
        header.Text = "NOME";
        header.Width = 415;
        header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        listView1.Columns.Add(header);


        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { "NOME_" + i }));
        }
    }

    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CheckBox Checked");

            //Aqui preciso desabilitar o CheckBox que foi Checked pra que não possa ser mais UnChecked
            //ou desbilitar a row inteira
        }

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia colocar o código desse ListView!?

Comment: Obrigado por responder, coloquei um código exemplo que criei agora, pois não estou com o código em mãos no momento e uma imagem de como seria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o evento `ItemCheck` que terá o efeito desejado (ou seja, será simulado assim, como esse objeto não pudesse mudar o seu status se ele estiver já checado), aonde após setar como checado ele não pode ser tirado o check. Lembrando que não existe `Enabled` nesse componente.

```
private void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked)
      {
          e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;
      }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema, agradeço muito.